# Multithreading in Oracle

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, oracle11g

I am working on Oracle 11g. I have a table which stores around 100 records. Two columns of importance to this question are:

```
ID
SQL
```

The SQL column contains Dynamic SQL query which needs to be executed. This Dynamic SQL will be updating a single table.

How can I use DBMS_SCHEDULER to execute the dynamic SQLs stored in SQL column in parallel (multi-threading) for say, 10 rows at at time. I do not want to execute all threads in parallel (since the number of records in this table can go upto 1000).

In case I am not clear enough with the problem statement, do let me know.

Please suggest!

Comment: Thanks Eric for correcting out that spelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either execute a series of jobs which each accept an ID and then process the associated SQL, which would be flexible, or you could use a scheduler chain in which you define a chain with ten steps, each of which executes on of the SQL's, with rules to start all the steps at the start of the chain.